# I have two points specified as lat/long(s) and would like to insert a new point in between them

Tags: c#, distance

I have two points specified as lat/long(s) and would like to insert a new point in between them a certain distance (in meters) from point the initial point.

**Presumably I convert the lat/longs to radians and then use a version of midpoint formula?**

How can i accomplish this task?

I'm living in c# land btw.

TIA

Comment: How far are the two points from each other? There's a simple approximation that's good enough for distances up to a few kilometers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact solution is not that simple (an approximate solution is just given by linear interpolation). You're not going to love it.

The trajectory follows a great circle, which is the intersection between the sphere and a plane through the center and the two given points.

First convert from [spherical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates) to Cartesian coordinates. Then by the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Matrix_notation) of the vectors from the center to the two points, determine the direction of the normal to the plane (normalize the vector). Then use the formula for [3D rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) around this axis and rotate the starting point. The rotation angle is given by the desired distance divided by the radius of the Earth. Finally, convert back to spherical coordinates.

Comment: You're right, I don't like it! Don't think i'll bother and just use  the mid point for what i need - thanks.